# How to add MBFloatingButton in custom MapBox navigation controller in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I want to add custom button to MBNavigationViewController.Please see the reference image with red circle.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: what is `MBNavigationViewController`?. Show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is looking for answer.
Please find following code.

```
MBNavigationViewController *nav = [[MBNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRoute:routeFinded directions:[MBDirections sharedDirections] style: nil
                                                locationManager: location];    
 MBNavigationView *navigationView = (MBNavigationView *)[nav.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
        UIStackView *navigationStackView = (UIStackView *)[navigationView.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
```

These above lines will get the UIStackView object.
By following we can add the view inside stackview

```
[navigationStackView addArrangedSubview:<yourview>];
```